# Serving a large CSS file

Tags: css

I have a large minified CSS file at around 50k, this is referenced by about 30 pages.

Would separating the CSS into one base file with separate CSS files for each page significantly reduce load time, or is serving one large file practically the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "one base file with separate CSS files"?

Comment: With the number of connections from the same domain being restricted I would guess that it would be about the same. I don't know 100% though. If you expect this to run on IE you may have an issue with not all the styles being recognized though. IE restricts the file size (or atleast did: http://joshua.perina.com/africa/gambia/fajara/post/internet-explorer-css-file-size-limit)

Comment: Your best bet is to split that into more files, and to run WebKit Audits and see whats going on with network and the load time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

50k really isn't that large - especially with most people's internet connections.

I'd keep the single file, because:

1. You only need a single HTTP request to load the entire CSS
2. CSS will be loaded for your entire website as soon as a single page is visited (which is nice for further browsing)

A similar topic would be the use of [sprite sheets](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/) - which is essentially the same thing in that one large file containing multiple images is favourable over many smaller images nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but serving one large file and caching it properly is definitely the way to go - ideally, that  will cause only one HTTP request per client.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer, but does the "@import" statement increase the http request? what about that approach?

Comment: @Ali yes, `@import` will cause another HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks man, so it's best to merge all css files or use special `@import` of CSS Preprocessors, right?

Comment: @Ali yes, so the end result is only one file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the majority of the css is being used by each page the ideal way to serve it is as a large file. HTTP Requests take time so having several small files requested by a page takes a while to load, not to mention the cap on the number of simultaneous connections. Second of all, and even more importantly, proper caching means that they only need to download the entire file once.

Answer (score -1):

Yes separating them for each page would reduce the load time for each page since each page would only be pulling the css that it needs.

Comment: Nope - this would actually pretty certainly *increase* loading time, as it would be guaranteed that each page needs an additional HTTP request - with the usual latency, that will take longer than loading the 50kb once and having them cached by the browser for every page on the site. The only exception to that *may* be *really* slow Internet connections like 14400b modem dial-up

Comment: No. You're forgetting caching.

Comment: But then you hit the number of max connections and overhead for HTTP requests.