# css best practices - combining all css into a single stylesheet?

Tags: css

I read somewhere that -

> You should put all CSS (files) into one single stylesheet

Question -

1) Is it good practice? if yes, then why?

Comment: Similar: [Serving a large CSS file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681111/serving-a-large-css-file/7681153#7681153).

Comment: Just because it's less requests to the server. Each request for an external image, stylesheet, script, etc. has some fixed overhead associated with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should combine all your CSS into one file to reduce the amount of requests made to your server.

A similar topic is [`sprite sheets`](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), the combination of multiple images into one large image to also reduce the amount of requests made to your server.

You'll find that loading 100x 5kb files is a lot slower than loading a single 500kb file.

---

When you're ready to upload your files to a live environment, you should also consider compressing your CSS and JavaScript files. There are a vast amount of online tools for this, eg:

- [CSS Compressor](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/).
- [JavaScript Compressor](http://javascriptcompressor.com/).
- [HTML Compressor](http://www.textfixer.com/html/compress-html-compression.php).

Comment: The CSS Compressor link goes to a parked domain now.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it good practice? if yes, then why?

Because with one css file, browser sends *one http request*, with multiple css file browsers sends multiple http requests causing slow response to user.

This is also mentioned in Yahoo's famous:

**[Exceptional Performance](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/)**

Check out:

[Rule 1 – Make Fewer HTTP Requests](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/04/rule_1_make_few/)

---

BTW, same goes true for **Javascript** (combine all in one) and images (use **css sprites** and single image)

---

**Interesting:**

There are two tools that can tell you how to speed up the page's speed:

- [Google's Page Speed Plugin](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)
- [Yahoo's YSlow Plugin](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)

Answer (score 1):

Because load time is an issue, and the more css files your website is requesting, the slower it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You should bundle all your JavaScript in single file and your css in another single file. The benefit of having all your code in single file is less http requests on server and so the server can serve more users.

At development time, its good to keep things separate for management but for deploying you can use tools that automatically minify and bundle your JS and css files.