# Performance on phonegap

Tags: javascript, performance, cordova

Resently I have created an PhoneGap app.

Now I want to make more Efficient as it is very slow.

So I am searching on google & SO that minify version is make more faster then regualar .js file

also according tho this.

[css best practices - combining all css into a single stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256299/css-best-practices-combining-all-css-into-a-single-stylesheet/9256361#9256361)

keeping everything on file is good thing from fatching file from server but as in Phonegap app everything is at client side.

now my Questions are

1) does minify improves notable performance?

2) is it good Practice to make diffenet .js file or put everything on same is good one?

Answer (score 0):

For your two questions my answer is quite similar.

2) Yes is always a good practice to write javascript in a different file as when you include that the file in you page almost every browser provides you the caching.
For the first time broswer looks into the cache and download the .js file from the server and store in its cache.
When again the same file is included it wil not download the js file but will refer to the cache.

This surely improves the performance.

1) As I explained above for the first time evrey js file gets download to client side. Now if you minify the js the download size will be very less hence will improve you performance. But it doesnt mean that you javascript code will start performing faster when you minify the js file.

Both the cases will improve the performance in some manner.

Comment: but in phonegap everything is on client side so now minify will affect or not?

Comment: phone gap will give you apk file. on installation it will place its html/js/css on you device somewhere. You browser will point to those file hence device will act as server

Comment: & as i have add link says that creating multiple file is not good. now i am confuse between your ans & theirs.

Comment: I am not saying create different js/css file. I am saying do not use inline css/js and do not write js/css in same html/jsp file.look there are factors that effect your performance. creating single file for css/js will also improve you performance as browser will not make more lookups for included files

Answer (score 0):

yeah you are right that why one should create a minify verstion of script if everything is going to run on client side , but in my experience there are two main benifits :

-One is while creating minify version , the compiler guides you about best practices and creates warning where required ( sencha cmd does).

-Other point is your app does reduce in size.

-You can have clean production version of your app.

Thanks

Comment: how about second question ? is it good practice to make different .js file ? becasue as i have manstioned link they are saying that dont make multiple file.

Comment: It's good for development, but bad in production. Break your program into multiple modules for easier development, join and minify them for deployment. Something like **require.js** will do the trick.

Comment: Pulah the are saying do not make 10 js/css files of 100 line. It will force your browser to make 10 request to download all the files. Instead create 1 single js/css with 1000 lines.

Comment: Yes I agree with Amit Sharma on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some alternative approach to it.
Basically minifying and deferred loading of JavaScript files is a good practice. However, you can also consider trying native UI widgets on your apps to render the page much faster.

I am using [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/) for a while and found its native component very efficient and high performance. It's open-source as well. Take a look at the [API reference](http://docs.monaca.mobi/en/reference/native_index/).

The alternative solution is to use Steroids. It is closed-source, but it provides similar functions and components.